# File name length parameters in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting a FileNotFoundError in collab when seeking to import an excel (.xls) workbook into a dataframe in Pandas.

I know the file is there, and that the path I'm using is correct. The file path is long. Is there an upper limit on characters in a file path when importing excel workbooks into pandas.

I'm trying to import multiple workbooks into pandas and then combine them into a single dataframe.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please post some code and info about your folder structure.

Comment: There is an upper limit on filenames depending on your OS. Don’t know what is the case with collab though

Comment: always good to use `from pathlib import Path`. then use this OO file system to test existence and open files into data frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can get filename too long issues.  However this is core python/host o/s
- good practice is always use OO file access methods offered by **Path**
- on my system if I try to generate a filename of 300 alpha characters I get an error from existence check.  i.e. limitation is not **pandas**

```
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np

f = Path.cwd().joinpath("".join([chr(c) for c in np.random.randint(65,65+26,200)]) + ".csv")

if not f.exists():
    pd.DataFrame({"date":pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", periods=20)}).to_csv(f, index=False)
    
if f.exists():
    print(pd.read_csv(f))
```